# What should my Android network service's lifetime be?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Hello i have a client server architecture with tcp socket connection in ANdroid. I have a socket listener thread in my service 'onStart()'. I want to reconnect to server after somehow lost connection. How can i design this issue? I tried some ways but i got into infinite loops in service start... Thanks for answering.

Listener code is like this...

```
@Override
    public void onStart(final Intent intent, int startId) {

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSTARTED!!");
        if(!mySocket.isConnected()){
            connectiontoServer();
        }

        clientListenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() { // TCP Socket Listener 

            public void run() {
                String line = new String();

                try {
                    while(mySocket.isConnected() && ((line = in.readLine()) != null)){
                        try{
                            Log.d(TAG, "service onStart-while true");        
                            String[] tokens = line.split(MessageClass.ayirac);
                            Log.d(TAG+"-MSG", line);
                            tokens = line.split(MessageClass.ayirac);
                            int msgCase = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);

                                 switch(msgCase){

                                    case -5:
                                        responseEntrance(line);
                                        break;

                                    case 1:
                                        responseLogin1(line);
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        responseRegister2(tokens);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;

                                 }
                            }catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d(TAG, "CATCH1 !");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if(!mySocket.isConnected()){
                            Log.d(TAG,"ConnectionDOWN! in catch2");
                            stopAndDestroyMyActivity();
                        }
                    }

                Log.d(TAG, "LISTENING FINISH!");
                stopAndDestroyMyActivity();
                }
        });
        clientListenerThread.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to connect after some time go with Timer class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html